# GStreamer pipeline not created for NTSC/PAL

Tags: opencv, pipeline, gstreamer, video-capture, python-gstreamer

I am creating an GStreamer pipeline for `NTSC/PAL` video feed. I have command that run on terminal

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video4:width=720:height=576:outfmt=yuy2 &
```

This command if I run on terminal it gives me video feed of my camera. But when I am creating an GStreamer pipeline it will show below error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1761) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Device '/dev/video4' has no supported format
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

Same thing if I run for HDSDI interface, it is working. The command I used for HDSDI is

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video8:width=720:height=576:outfmt=yuy2 &
```

and pipeline created is

```
v4l2src io-mode=0 device=/dev/video8 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=(string)YV12 ! videoconvert ! appsink
```

I tried creating the pipeline for it but I am unable to create it for `NTSC/PAL`. I tried below pipeline:

```
v4l2src io-mode=0 device=/dev/video8 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=(string)YV12 ! videoconvert ! appsink
```